# How do I launch Ubuntu after installation

Tags: startup

I am done with the installation  of Ubuntu. If I turn my chromebook on I see the white screen with the red exclamation point. Then it goes to black terminal screen and prompts me to log in. I do that and it tells me the last time I logged in. The next line reads "user@chrubuntu:" I type CTRL + L to launch the program but it doesn't  do anything.  I am stumped as to what I should next. I want to get out of this terminal  and start using Ubuntu. ( version 15.04)

Comment: try to do Ctrl+Alt+F7

Comment: or type `startx` followed by `ENTER`. If `startx` fails then post the exact output as an edit to your question.

Comment: CTRL + ALT + F7 doesnothing. When I do start x  and Enter there is a server error.

Comment: Its not start, its `startx`. Post the exact error.

Comment: I did that and It still says server error. Before that it says Connection refused.

Comment: Try this   `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xorg` & then restart.

Comment: I see Setting up xorg. How long do I wait for this?

Comment: @Fabby Unlike Crouton, Chrubuntu is stock Ubuntu in a dual boot with Chrome OS, and questions about Chrubuntu are not off topic. Your bootloader observation does not apply here, because Chrubuntu has finished booting and Sabria has already logged in to a terminal.

Comment: @karel: Thanks for the info...  Close vote retracted, dumb comment deleted.  **;-)**

Comment: @SabriaKiaraPage: As you're a reputation 1 user: If the answer below helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of it, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: I entered the command: sudo service lightdm start. What happens is user@chrubuntu appears.

Answer (score 0):

After you have logged in in the terminal type:

```
sudo systemctl start graphical.target
```

and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to bring up your default login screen and then login to your Ubuntu desktop environment as usual.

If you can't login to your desktop environment because of a kernel or driver issue, then you could try installing Crouton on your Chromebook instead of Chrubuntu. Crouton runs on top of Chrome OS and at the same time as Chrome OS. Therefore, it uses the kernel provided by Chrome OS, all the drivers from Chrome OS, and everything else that is provided by Chrome OS.

The other alternative is to stay with Chrubuntu and always start the login display manager from the terminal by running `sudo systemctl start graphical.target` if that works.